# Angular 4+ Inconsistient HttpErrorResponse error property type

Tags: angular

When I handle `HttpErrorResponse` I have to use this piece of code to check type of error because in IE 11 `event.error` type is string whereas in other browsers it is `Object`:

```
  private handleResponseError(event: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (event.status === 403) {
      if (event.error) {
        let error;
        if (typeof event.error === 'string') {
          try {
            error = JSON.parse(event.error);
          } catch (error) { }
        } else {
          error = event.error;
        }
        // do sth with error
      }
    }
  }
```

Any idea why?